# How to use the results of detect.py from YOLOv5 to make a simple stock control function

Tags: python

I am using the yolov5 algorithm to do object detection so I can then use the results of the detection to decrement the identified product to the existing stock.

At this moment I already have the module trained and it is correctly detecting the object, but I can't import the variables from detect.py to the file where I have the stock control function.

I would like to know how can I proceed to get the necessary data.

In the stock control function, I'm running detect.py in the background, I don't know if I have to change that, but below you have the script of the function under development, it might help to understand the goal.

```
import subprocess
from detect import classes

HPSF = 300
NM = 300


def New_Scan():
    cmd = "python detect.py --weights C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PESTA\\Scripts\\runs\\train\\exp4\\weights\\best.pt --img 416 --conf 0.8 --source 0"
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell= True)

    if classes == 0:
           HPSF = HPSF - 1
    elif classes == 1:
           NM = NM -1

def Check_Stock():
    print("Halloween Pumpkin Spice Faces: ", HPSF)
    print("Nestum Mel: ", NM)


def menu():
    print("[1] New Product")
    print("[2] Check Avaible Stock")
    print("[0] Exit")


menu()
option= int(input("Enter option: "))

while option !=0:
    if option == 1:
        print("Scanning New Product")
        New_Scan()
    elif option == 2:
        print("Avaible Stock")
        Check_Stock()
    else:
        print("invalid option")
    print()
    menu()
    option= int(input("Enter option: "))
```

The error that appears is this:

Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'classes' from 'detect' (c:\Users\User\Desktop\PESTA\Scripts\detect.py)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [detect.py](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py) does not return any variable while running. It means that you need to modify such a file to get what you want, in this case, the detected object categories and bounding box coordinates. Indeed, this option will provide a fast answer in real-time detection. Otherwise, you can save results to a txt file and import it to your code, but it will take longer to process.